# Admin can add price of product based on day of the week [ Model relation ]

Tags: laravel, uml, class-diagram

Hi i have a hard time making successful relation between models.
basically i have **Product Model** and **Price Model** so i want to add price of Product **based on day of the week**

Comment: I guess you need to be more specific. What are your price a product models?

Comment: Admin can add rice of product based on season of year.
Ex: Price for Holidays, Price for Vacations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can model this as association class:

[image]

A `Product` has a basic `ProductPrice` (`basicPrice`)  and additionally a number of `seasonPrice` entries.